# React + Laravel взаимодействие, роутинг

Tags: reactjs, laravel

React и Laravel работают на домене https://host.com/

Доступ к api-маршрутам с фронта осуществляется так:

`fetch({ route: 'api/url', body, });`

Как получить доступ к маршрутам в файле web.php из React?

В файле web.php есть маршрут

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'web test';
});
```

Код React-роута:

```
fetch(
  {
    route: `test?id=${String(body.id)}&lang=${String(
      body.lang
    )}`,
    isNeedAuth: body.isNeedAuth,
  },
  true
);
```

Comment: Что значит получить доступ к маршрутам?

Comment: как обратиться к маршруту "/test" в web.php?

Comment: Должно быть так fetch('https://host.com/web.php/?test') или fetch('https://host.com/web.php/test')

Comment: Обращаться так же как и к api маршрутам, только без префикса api... `fetch({ route: '/test', body, });`

Comment: @SwaD ерунды не пишите

Comment: **React + Laravel** - это использование пакета `php artisan breeze:install react` или отдельные проекты?

Comment: думаю отдельные проекты

Comment: просто fetch({ route: '/test', body, }) мы пробовали - неполучается

Comment: @MyNick если это отдельнгые приложения, вообще не пойму причины вопроса) взаимодействуйсте по http как угодно

Comment: `php artisan route:list` ищите в списке свой роут test, он есть там?

Comment: есть, GET|HEAD | test | | Closure | web

Comment: Странно тогда.. Вы как пробовали - что именно не получалось? Ошибка была какая, или что? В network смотрели запрос?

Comment: по-моему перекидывало на  https://host.com, точно не помню

Comment: А просто в браузере если открывать то роут работает?

Comment: @MyNick Если перекидывает куда-то, это значит, что middleware какой-то впихнули (по типу auth в группе), просто адрес редиректить никуда не должен. Ну и по прямой ссылке откройте - редиректит?

Comment: При открытии по прямой ссылки из браузера - открывает главную страницу. Ответ: статус 200, "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app"

Comment: дабавил код react-роута